# Unable to connect to Dockerized CherryPy Server while using `cherrypy.tree.mount`

Tags: python-3.x, docker, containers, cherrypy

I'm unable to connect to CherryPy server running inside a docker container from my system when i use `cherrypy.tree.mount` but when I do `cherrypy.quickstart()` I can connect to the server. A curl request to `localhost:8080` with `cherrypy.tree.mount` gives a `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` error.

**App file which works**

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
   @cherrypy.expose
   def index(self):
      return "Hello World!"

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), '/', {'global': {'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0','server.socket_port': 8080}})
```

**App file which fails**

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

    cherrypy.tree.mount(HelloWorld(), '/', {'global':{'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0','server.socket_port': 8080}})

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir -p /opt/server

WORKDIR /opt/server
ADD . /opt/server
VOLUME /opt/server

RUN pip install cherrypy

EXPOSE 8080

CMD python app.py
```

I have to use `cherrypy.tree.mount` because I have to run multiple applications on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

I was giving the configuration wrong. The right way to set global configs is:

`cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0','server.socket_port': 8080})`

once that was set it is working fine. configs on `cherrypy.tree.mount` is for each application.